# How to clone an axios instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a global axios instance which I use across my application. I want to update headers locally for a particular request. But the headers update is updating the global defaults. I wanted to understand the best way of doing this. Currently I am hacking my way into resetting the headers. Also toyed around with the idea of deep cloning the global axios instance. It just feels like an important feature to have, but couldn't find anything the docs, except for a github issues talking about sub-instances. (https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1170)

EDIT: sorry for not providing code. This is my setup to give an idea:
Following is my global axiosClient(in file `apiClient.js`), with some interceptors added(not shown in code).

```
const axiosClient = axios.create({
baseURL,
headers: {
Authorization: <bearer_token>,
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
.
 }
});
```

In my modules, I import the same client to make api requests as such:

```
import axiosClient from '../apiClient';

export function someRequest({ file }) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  const initHeader = axiosClient.defaults.headers['Content-Type'];
  axiosClient.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data'; // I want to make this change only for the local instance
  const request = axiosClient.post('parse-rebalance-data', formData);
  axiosClient.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = initHeader; //I have to reset the changes I made to the axiosClient
  return request;
}
```

Now my question again is,(1) do I need to do it in this hacky way, or(2) should I look into deep cloning a local copy, or(3) is there a documented way to doing it which I am missing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? Code would help.

If you're passing in headers correctly to an individual request it should not update the global headers, but its hard to tell till you provide some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that Axios instances do, is set *default values* for the configuration. You can, however pass any other configuration to each call by using the `config` parameter, as you would with the global Axios:

```
import axiosClient from '../apiClient';

export function someRequest({ file }) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  return axiosClient.post('parse-rebalance-data', formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}});
}
```

The headers specified in the `config` argument are merged with those in the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually create an instance from another instance.

So for example you could have:

```js
// src/services/http.js

import axios from 'axios';

const http = axios.create({
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json'
  },
  withCredentials: true
});

export default http;
```

And then where you need a more specific instance:

```js
// src/services/pouic.js

import http from './services/http';

// Defines common base URL for all services in this module.
const httpPouic = http.create({
  baseURL: 'https://pouic.com/api'
});

export default {
  getPouic: async function () {
    const pouics = await httpPouic({
      method: 'get'
      url: '/pouic-list'
    });

    return pouics.data;
  }
};
```

Be careful, in case you use Axios with TypeScript, there's a [known bug](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5095) with the `AxiosInstance` type which doesn't reference the `create` method.

Comment: Error: Property 'create' does not exist on type 'AxiosInstance'.

Comment: Not sure where this type comes from but clearly the method exists: https://axios-http.com/docs/instance

Comment: I think you’re mixing up the APIs between the `axios` type and the `instance` type. The `create` isn’t listed under the `Instance methods`. I suggest you try it before suggesting it to others.

Comment: I suggest you try it before saying it doesn't work. Run `const inst = axios.create();` then `const inst2 = inst.create();`. `inst2` exists and works as expected.

Comment: Hmm I totally did try it and even your last example and get this compile error: `Property 'create' does not exist on type 'AxiosInstance'`. I'm using the latest Axios v1.4.

Comment: It seems to be related to TypeScript as highlighted in this issue https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5095

Comment: Great find! Too bad for the bug, confusing many. Can you edit your answer with this?

Comment: Good idea, it's done.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

More you can read here:

https://axios-http.com/docs/instance

Comment: This is not what I asked. I don't want to create a local instance. Since there are interceptors on the global instance, which I don't want to copy again and again on every local instance.